# Getting error while executing SenchaTouch sample project in android?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to developing android applications with Sencha Touch. By following the documentation from [Hybrid applications using phonegap and sencha touch](http://android.amolgupta.in/2011/07/hybrid-applications-using-phonegap-and.html)  i created sample app. When i am trying to execute the following sample project it is getting error as **"08-06 12:28:51.394: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.senchademoproj.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.demo.senchademoproj-1.apk]
"**. And my logcat output is

[image]

My AndroidManifest.xml file is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.demo.senchademoproj"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6" />

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I don't know what the mistake i am getting. I checked my AndroidManifest.xml file twice.

Can anyone please suggest me what's the mistake i am doing & **Please suggest me how & from where to start learning & developing of android applications using Sencha Touch Library.....**

Comment: Exception says that there is no such class MainActivity in your package com.demo.senchademoproj. You should check that file MainActivity.java is present in your soruce folder in packge com.demo.senchademoproj

Comment: my MainActivity.java is present in com.demo.senchademoproj only & everything is mentioned correctly in Manifest.xml file but don't know why that particular error is getting.....

Comment: have you tried cleaning project and then run it?

Comment: ya, but getting the same error....

Comment: may be this is because your base class is not resolved. Have you included your phonegap jar to build path?

Comment: ya, i added phonegap.jar file in build path & for better case i created lib folder & added there also.... I cleaned my project & checked project twice but not getting whats the mistake is. If without adding Sencha files to project it is working good. After adding Sencha files it is getting error.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing sencha touch/phonegap/jquery mobile application with android eclipse there is a plugin available.just install that plugin in your eclipse and you easily will be able to create sencha project in eclipse...

follow steps below

every time including jquery for every new project is not a smart task,i am giving u one link by which u will be able to install phonegap plugin in eclipse,so after following that u will get such symbol as given in below image. After clicking on that symbol u will be able to create phonegap project directly from that,and project will automatically include all jquery min js, phonegap.js etc files required for creating phonegap environment.here is a image!

[image]

and here is a link u need to follow for installing phonegap plugin(I.E Sencha touch plugin) in eclipse follow all steps given on than have a look at this link

[STEP1](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start)

[STEP2](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/startdetails)

and that's it after following this you will be able to create sencha project in eclipse....

for more detail see [MY POST](http://tech-aamir.blogspot.in/2012/06/making-phonegap-development-environment.html)

i hope this will solve ur query....
best of luck